# Classification using correlation

Tags: machine-learning, correlation, classification, intraclass-correlation

Given two correlation matrix (each $p \times p$), where each belongs to a different group, is it possible to classify a new sample into one of the group (based on the correlation matrix only)? What can be possible best machine learning method in such situation?

Comment: I would try first a Quadratic Discriminant Analysis...

Comment: will the correlation between the new sample and all the other samples be given?

Comment: @Memming If yes, what are the options?

Answer (score 2):

The discriminant analysis is my best guess. However, I would not stick to the correlation matrixs. You might try other methods if possible.